# How to run specified sub module play application in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a play project that contains some sub projects.
I can run play application 1 or 2 in the typesafe activator's console -
selectively like below.

```
$ activator "project collector" run
$ activator "project scheduler" run
```

But, I couldn't find any references and manuals to do this in IntelliJ.
What should I do?

The project structure is like this.

```
root
  - collector (play application 1)
    - app
    - conf
    - build.sbt
  - scheduler (play application 2)
    - app
    - conf
    - build.sbt
  - core
    - src
    - build.sbt
  - util
    - src
    - build.sbt
  - build.sbt
```

And root's build.sbt file is like below.

```
import sbt.Keys._
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.xxxx",
  version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
  javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(core, collector, scheduler, util).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  settings(
    name := "collector",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
  )


lazy val core = project.in(file("core")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val collector = project.in(file("collector")).
  dependsOn(core, util).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala, SbtWeb)

lazy val scheduler = project.in(file("scheduler")).
  dependsOn(core, util).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala, SbtWeb)

lazy val util = project.in(file("util")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  dependsOn(core)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.spray" % "spray-io_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "io.spray" % "spray-can_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "io.spray" % "spray-client_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "io.spray" % "spray-http_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "io.spray" % "spray-httpx_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "io.spray" % "spray-util_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.3.7",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-contrib_2.11" % "2.3.7",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0"
)     


Keys.fork in Test := false

addCommandAlias("cc", ";clean;compile")
```

Answer (score 1):

On intellij
   click menu

- Run > Edit Configuration > "+" > SBT Task

  - on SBT Task Details pane,
  - in "Tasks" Textbox type in
  - "project collector" run
  - in "Name" Textbox type in a Name example "run collector"
  - click "ok"
- click "Run" > "run collector"

Repeat the steps above for your other project
References

- IntelliJ CE 2017.1
- SBT 0.13.13

Answer (score 0):

`Play` submodules are not meant to be run separately, they depend on `main` project.

> - Sub-projects do not have their own build file, but share the parent project’s build file.
> - Particularly, there must be only one application.conf file and only one routes file.

More details [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTSubProjects).